# MediaWiki alternatives for small business?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

Are there any good alternative wiki's to MediaWiki out there for a small business?  Mostly we are just wanting to use it for documentation. MediaWiki is a fine (and slightly outdated) piece of software, but it doesn't even officially support basic things like controlling who has access to what page/article, which is an important feature for us.

Comment: Note, this question is about a documentation solution. The fact that it relies on a website is not really relevant, in my opinion. It's a piece of software they install, maintain, and use locally. Questions about websites are not allowed on this site, but I think this case falls more into the "computer software" that you install, than into the "remote webservice".

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment is all about... Are you saying that people aren't allowed to ask about what type of wiki software would meet their needs the best?

Comment: it wasn't really a comment to you, more to potential closers. We have strict policies on superuser about the scope of it (at least we try). You can see more details in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com). Website questions are not allowed (mostly to avoid filling the site with "facebook/gmail/twitter support questions"), and as such, since your question involved a website, it can be a bit in a foggy area according to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to their description:

> [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) is a standards
>   compliant, simple to use Wiki, mainly
>   aimed at creating **documentation of any
>   kind**. It is targeted at developer
>   teams, workgroups and small companies.

Comment: It came down between PMWiki and Dokuwiki and it looks like DokuWiki might be better for us. Looks like configuration is easier and the LDAP integration is a snap.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows servers, you might take a look at [ScrewTurn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/) - I used it in a previous job, where it was a central knowledge repository. It seemed to work reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend taking a look at [Atlassian Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence). It's the most user-friendly and versatile wiki I've seen thus far, which makes adoption far more likely than for, e.g., MediaWiki.

It's commercial, but if you have 10 users max, you are eligible for their "startup license", which is only $10 (proceeds going to charity as well).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a small business, and you already have servers or similar, the first thing that comes to mind is Microsoft Sharepoint. (Just the default Sharepoint services that comes with Windows Server, not Sharepoint Portal Server).

It is built for businesses and there are many templates including a WIKI system.

...That being said, if you don't have a Windows server, this won't help and there are hundreds out there - I can't really recommend any (as I have only used MediaWiki)... And I think there has been loads of similar posts here.

Comment: Also, that wiki system is really just based on HTML code. No simple and quick MediaWiki-style markup.

Answer (score 0):

We use [TWiki](http://twiki.org/), what I like the most about it is:

- Fine-grained [access-control](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/TWikiAccessControl) scheme
- Organization of content into '[Webs](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/ManagingWebs)' (each representing a different area of collaboration)
- It's Structured Wiki [features](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/StructuredWiki#Features_of_a_Structured_Wiki)